# Remove whiskers in box-whisker-plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Is there a straightforward way to remove the whiskers from a box-whisker-plot in `ggplot2` in `R`? I'd like to keep only the boxes themselves.

MWE:

```
library("ggplot2")
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We only need to add the argument `coef = 0`:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, coef = 0) # Or outlier.size = -1 instead of outlier.shape = NA
```

[image]

Comment: That's great!  How did you know this, though?  I couldn't find any documentation discussing this **`coef`**.  I understand what it is doing, but it seems so powerful that I suspect there is a **`coef`** that I can adjust on other plots that might be quite helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: @MikeWilliamson Thank you. To be honest I don't remember. In the `geom_boxplot` documentation it says that this argument determines the "length of the whiskers as multiple of IQR. Defaults to 1.5", so probably I tried 0. For boxplots using the R base is more difficult to find the arguments needed (`?bxp`) whisklty and staplelty: `boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, whisklty = 0, staplelty = 0)`

Comment: Is it only me? I had to exchange `outlier.size = 0` to ` outlier.shape = NA` to make outliers disappear.

Comment: @JelenaČuklina It used to work, not anymore. You can use `outlier.size = -1` but the best option to hide outliers is the one you suggested:  `outlier.shape = NA`. I will edit my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

One way would be to use `stat_summary_df()` to calculate meadian, 25 and 75 percentiles and then plot those data with `geom="crossbar"`. Automatically it can be done with `"median_hilow"` inside the `stat_summary_df()`. For this you will need to add library `Hmisc` and also define function `stat_summary_df(`) before plotting. Default values for `"median_hilow"` is 2.5 and 97.5 percentiles, so you need to add argument `conf.int=0.5`.

```
 stat_sum_df <- function(fun, geom="crossbar", ...) {
    stat_summary(fun.data=fun, colour="red", geom=geom, width=0.2, ...)
 }

library(Hmisc)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
   stat_sum_df("median_hilow",conf.int=0.5,fill="white")
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. The `conf.int` (now?, ggplot2 3.3.5) needs to be passed through `fun.args`. So  `stat_sum_df("median_hilow", fun.args = list(conf.int=0.5), fill="white")`